# Hide delayed div to new visitor, show immediately to returning visitor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found similar code elsewhere on this site but can't get it to work for my situation.

I'm trying to delay showing a div (8 second delay in this case) to NEW visitors but if cookie is set then show the div immediately to RETURNING visitors.

Currently, it seems that the first part works--showing the div to new visitors after 8 seconds--and my code sets the cookie but the second part--showing the div immediately to returning visitors--doesn't work at all and, in fact, NEVER seems to show the div content.

I've tried everything I can think to move around but no luck.

Here's the relevant code (including cookie code) all placed in the HEAD section:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showbox() {
    document.getElementById("show-this").style.visibility = "visible";
}
if (!readCookie('visitedPreviously')) { //if he/she is a new user
     setTimeout("showbox()", 8000); // after 8 secs    createCookie('visitedPreviously', 'visitedPreviously', 3); // 365 days persistence
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="show-this" style="visibility: hidden"><div class="center-this"><a href="mylink" target="_blank"><img src="mysource" alt="some text" /></a></div>
</div>
```

I've tried moving the "function showbox" to the BODY, tried if/else statements inside that function, moving code to a .js files, using css, and more but now I just need some help as I obviously don't know what I'm doing.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!readCookie('visitedPreviously')) { //if he/she is a new user
  setTimeout("showbox()", 8000); // after 8 secs 
  createCookie('visitedPreviously', 'visitedPreviously', 3); // 365 days persistence
} else {
  showbox();
}
```

you just forgot the else :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this seems to make it worse as the page no longer shows the div block to new users and no longer sets the cookie. The scripts seems to do nothing whatsoever.